# How to remove specific characters from php string?

Tags: php, string, date, post, replace

I have an array with a bunch of data. One of the indexes provides a user with a string of numbers that I will later convert into a readable format with javascript. The string is as follows:

```
$dueDate = "1111-11-11T11:11";
```

I get that value with the following code:

```
$dueDate = $_POST['dueDate'];
```

I need to remove the ' - ', ' T ', and ' : ' characters from the string. I have tried the trim() function, and str_replace() function but still does not work.

I was hoping to use a built-in function rather than loop through the string. But if that is not possible I know I can turn the string into an array and loop through it.

Comment: `str_replace` is correct, so you must have used it wrong.

Comment: Or when working with dates `echo date('Ymdhi', strtotime($dueDate));`

Comment: AbraCadaver your suggestion works for my case. Any problems I need to consider?

Answer (score 1):

As your working with a date string and your most likely going to want to validate the POST input too, you might as well use datetime. Parse it from expected input format, fail to parse is free validation.. then just format the date to your desired format on output.

```
<?php
// example, not copy and paste
if (!$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', $_POST['dueDate'])) {
    echo 'Invalid date';
} else {
    echo $date->format('Ymdhi');
}
```

- **DateTime::createFromFormat** - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
- **->format()** - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `str_replace` fairly easy.
[**In the docs**](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) it says that the arguments for `search` and `replacement` values can be arrays.

You could do something like this:

```
$dueDate = str_replace(['-','T', ':'], '', $dueDate);
```

An alternative for more complex replacements would be using a regular expression
via [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: This *does* work, so like I said above, you must have done it wrong.

Comment: @Thepurplelounge.com assuming your Targetstring really is `1111-11-11T11:11` this has to work. 
See this example: https://3v4l.org/U1sTd